# What can you do with VHDL beside circuit design?

Tags: vhdl

Is there interesting projects written in VHDL (possibly along with other languages) that serve beyond just circuit design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with VHDL in Xilinx and done electrical circuit design as you have said. You can use vhdl and assembly to code for numerous different projects such as writing the code behind a microprocessor such as intel 8088 or running a client server simple program using the RS232 port between two computers etc. Probably a million things you can do with it but the only limitations are that generally the language itself (VHDL) was designed to emulate and code and test hardware and its functioning. Meant for simulation and not really to code for anything else, I suggest you try other languages that can be used for better projects.